# dojo toolkit question about loading the base dojo.js file

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am getting used to the dojo toolkit. So my question is does the following code mean to load the base dojo code?

```
var djConfig = {  
     baseScriptUri: "js/dojo/"  
 };
```

Would I use the following code if I am using a CDN?

```
var djConfig = {    
     baseScriptUri: "http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/"    
 };
```

or would I write the code this way?

```
var djConfig = {    
     baseScriptUri: "http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/"    
 };
```

I am looking at a lot of dojo toolkit examples from the following website and they all have this code:

[http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0570_*Dojo-toolkit/Catalog0570*_Dojo-toolkit.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0570__Dojo-toolkit/Catalog0570__Dojo-toolkit.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loading Dojo

No. **This code won't load any javascript file in your browser**.

djConfig is the base configuration for the dojo framework (the way it loads resources, locales, parsing configuration...). Actually, the `baseScriptUri` key is not mandatory and tells dojo where to load additional resources (in case you changed the directory architecture).

So you still need that good old `<script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.js"
            djConfig="YOUR CONFIG HERE"></script>`.

For further questions, what version are you using?

### Mode info on XDomain loading

If you want to load a XDomain version of dojo, [you have to configure djConfig accordingly](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/xDomain.html) with `useXDomain = true`.

And don't forget to sprinkle `dojo.addOnLoad()` here and there when you expect your code to load other parts of dojo (that's the downside of XDomain loading).

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="useXDomain:true"></script>
```

Comment: I am using 1.3.2. so this does not have anything to do with djConfig.baseUrl?

Comment: Ok so dojo gives this example can you break it down to me?  

<script type="text/javascript">

  djConfig = {
   isDebug: true,
   parseOnLoad: true,
   baseUrl: "./",
   modulePaths: {
       "coolio": "scripts/coolio"
   },
   xdWaitSeconds: 10
  };
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.0.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dijit.ColorPalette");
  dojo.require("coolio.actions");
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
   coolio.actions.foo();
  });
 </script>

Comment: You miss the "useXDomain = true" in you djConfig

Comment: And seriously, stop switching dojo version :-) dojo 1.1+ is the min you should do, especially for Xdomain loading purposes.

Comment: I had to redo the <script> tag to make it work
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="useXDomain:true">

Comment: sorry about the typo - I just edited my answer to make it right